# How does Maven use external dependencies in your own project?

Tags: maven

I had a quick question on how Maven configures dependencies in the pom.xml file. In my project's pom.xml file, when I add a dependency tag and provide the artifact id and group id, how/where does Maven store those dependencies to use in my project? Since Maven is a central repository, does Maven use the internet to pull the dependencies or does it download the repositories in your local machine and use it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven repository is of three types :

- Local
- Central
- Remote

Maven first starts finding in **Local Repository** created by Maven in %USER_HOME% directory. To override the default location, mention another path in Maven settings.xml file available at %M2_HOME%\conf directory.
When Maven does not find any dependency in a local repository, it starts searching in the **Central repository**.
Sometimes, Maven does not find a mentioned dependency in the central repository as well. It then stops the build process and output error message to console. To prevent such situation, Maven provides a concept of **Remote Repository**, which is the developer's own custom repository containing required libraries or other project jars.

For user-defined jars, you also need to specify :

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>in-project</id>
     <name>Name_of_your_project</name>
     <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard configuration, Maven looks first in your local Maven repository (`.m2/repository` in your user directory) and if it does not find anything, it tries to download from the remote repositories that you specified. If you did not specify any, it will use MavenCentral.

When Maven finds something, it will be downloaded to the local Maven repository for future use. If you have `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies, they will be updated regularly.